# How can i get price list of available ec2 instance , i tried api request but i can't get price value in response of t2 type instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

```
def price_list_of_instance
  pricing = Aws::Pricing::Client.new(
            region: "us-east-1",
            access_key_id: "XXXX",
            secret_access_key: "XXXX"
           )

  resp = pricing.get_products({
         filters: [{
               field: "instanceType",
               type: "TERM_MATCH",
               value: "t2.medium",
               },
              ],
          format_version: "aws_v1",
          max_results: 1,
          service_code: "AmazonEC2"
        })

end
```

is there any other api or alternative solution  equivalent for this problem, which provide price list of ec2 t2 instance type?

Comment: The problem is most likely not with the API, but with your filter.  Can you get the pricing for *any* instance type?

Comment: @ Michael - sqlbot i got response ,when i passed t2.nano , t2.micro , t2.large , t2.xlarge , t2.2xlarge  in filter , however i can't get response when i passed t2.medium .